# Maven deploy: deployment should fail if artifact already exists

Tags: maven, deployment

If I configure my pom.xml as below:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-deploy</id>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <serverId>nexus</serverId>
                <nexusUrl>https://nexus/</nexusUrl>
                <skipStaging>false</skipStaging>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Then what happens is that on executing mvn deploy -this will deploy projectName-1.0-20180323.065217-1.jar on Nexus and the next deployment will have projectName-1.0-20180323.065217-2.jar deployed on nexus.

Is it possible to check if the snapshot version (in this case 1.0) is already present in nexus repo (and it gives a fail message that the version cannot be deployed).

The deployed version should be named as projectName-1.0.jar instead of projectName-1.0-20180323.065217-1.jar

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  :)   I tried to edit your post to make it easier to understand.  Please read it and make sure that it makes sense to you.  Your question seems generally unclear... but I also don't know anything about Maven or Nexus... so it could be me. :)

Comment: thanks  Boober Bunz ..It looks good

Comment: First why are you configuring the deploy plugin ? There us usually no need to do that. Just define the version of the maven-deploy-plugin this is already handled by the life cycle. Furthermore a SNAPSHOT by definition is intended to be overwritten cause it means under development. If you like to have artifacts which can't be overwritten (immutable) this is called a release which can't be modified at all.

Comment: I need to provide nexusUrl specific to project and I am using maven invoker to deploy application.

Comment: @DeeptiPillai you dont need to configure deploy plugin explicitly, you just need to give distributionManagement tag to provide nexus Url

Comment: at your nexus you need to create to specific repository for release and snapshot

Comment: Even if I do not configure the version getting deployed is same as mentioned in the question.

Comment: When I run deploy script it will deploy the artifact to nexus repo. But this version of artifact already exist in repo. Is there a way to skip deploy phase if version in pom.xml equal version which already exist in nexus repo.

Answer (score 0):

The mvn deploy will fail if the artifact to be uploaded is already in the repository

Note: only if you upload as a "RELEASE", not a "SNAPSHOT".

Your build could check first if that release version exists:

mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=g:a:v -o -DrepoUrl=file://path/to/your/repo